# How do I run Ruby code on a button click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I have a Rails partial, and a Ruby script I want to run when I click a button in the partial.

How do I do this?

This is the script I want to run - I have it in `<%= %>` tags right now.

```
 <%= require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(table_string)

doc.xpath('//table//tr').each do |row|
  row.xpath('td').each do |cell|
    print '"', cell.text.gsub("\n", ' ').gsub('"', '\"').gsub(/(\s){2,}/m, '\1'), "\", "
  end
  print "\n"
end
%>
```

I want to have a button that runs that snippet when I click it.

Comment: If you want a button to run ruby code (which must be done on the server) it sounds like you want to tie that button to an ajax request which leads to a controller action that will run the code, correct?

Comment: As often as I see questions like this, I felt prompted to write a blog entry for it.  Does this help any? http://dgrmm.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/web-application-101/

Comment: That helps a lot! I'm 17 and I've taught myself everything I know about programming so posts like these help me learn a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create a controller
- Create an action that will contain the code you want to run
- Set up your routes

Ex:

```
resources :my_resources do
    collection do
         get :your_action
     end
 end
```

And your link should be something like: `link_to "text", your_action_my_resources_path`.

Comment: So I have to create a controller? There's no way to just run it from a partial?

Comment: Well, if you put this code in your partial, it will run, but when the partial is rendered, not when the user will click the button. You could do it in javascript otherwise.

Comment: @Slicekick: No there's not. It's M-V-C. Controller decides what to do upon any request. :)

Comment: Ok, I understand! I will accept your answer when I get it to work.